# Flutter firestore compound query

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

i'd like to know if there's a way to query firebase firestore collection in Flutter adding more than one field to the query. I tried some ways but i didn't realize how to do that. For example:

```
CollectionReference col = Firestore.instance
    .collection("mycollection");

col.where('nome', isEqualTo: 'Tyg');
col.where('valor', isLessThan: '39');
```

Someone, please, have some way to do that? i am new in flutter and not getting the way.

Comment: Have you tried `var query = col.where('nome', isEqualTo: 'Tyg').where('valor', isLessThan: '39');`?

Comment: Hmm, I will try this way and let you know okay. Thank you so much for reply.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Building Firestore queries follows a "builder pattern". Every time you call `where` it returns a new query object. So the code you have constructs two queries, that you don't assign to anything.

```
CollectionReference col = Firestore.instance
    .collection("mycollection");

Query nameQuery = col.where('nome', isEqualTo: 'Tyg');
Query nameValorQuery = nameQuery.where('valor', isLessThan: '39');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaining Frank, now i'd like to know if is possible to make a OR clause like SQL, for example:
Query nameQuery = col.where('nome', isEqualTo: 'Tyg' or isEqualTo: 'Xtg'), or even if have a way to do as a LIKE in SQL. I thank you so much for helped.

Comment: One thing that i think strange is that when i used isLessThan: 39, it doesnt return any value, but when i put isEqualTo: 36, it returned the document that contains the value. So i thought that the isLessThan must return the 36 cause is less than 39, i am wrong?

Comment: Neither `OR` nor `LIKE` queries are supported. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321. While this is for the JavaScript SDK, these are server-side operations so typically land in all platforms at/around the same time once the server supports them.

Comment: Oh that's not good to know, i was looking for something like this (teamsCollection.where("members", "array_contains", {123, 345, 234})), to see documents that have some itens in the array, so for example, if a document has 123 key in the array enter in the result, if have 234 and etc. I will have to think about how to make a different way. Thank you for the help Frank.

Comment: This page describes how to get started with that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays But you'll still need a separate query for each member.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you, but there's a way to joing results of queries? for example, i can filter documents that contains one item in the array, then filter documents that have another etc, then joing all the results in one list in flutter? 
Trying explaing better i want to find documents that have in the array 123 or 345 or 675, so i can do threen queries and put it all toguether in the list? Maybe i am thinking more as SQL.

Answer (score 0):

### Jan 2023 Update - Now Supported

You can do this with `Filter`. See more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries

```dart
var query = db.collection("cities")
  .where(
    Filter.and(
      Filter("state", isEqualTo: "CA"),
    Filter.or(
      Filter("capital", isEqualTo: true),
      Filter("population", isGreaterThan: 1000000)
    )));
```