# Is the firestore cloud database appropriate for specific queries?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my application I need to search by multiple keys, e.g. price between, equal city, area between and then sort these values ​​by date added. Is the use of a firestore cloud when we want to filter data and sort it a good choice?
I read the documentation and I was surprised by the number of limitations in the cloud firestore

I know that you can use indexes, but in the case of filtering through many different values ​​at a time, does it make sense?

EDIT:
Little example:

[image]

and wants to have a menu with filtering and selecting each value and the possibility of sorting, e.g. by price or date of the offer. For example user would like to choose area between 50 and 80 and city equal to 'NY' etc and then sort it by price.

Comment: If you update your question with a screenshot of sample document and then explain what kind of queries you want to perform it'll be best. Also querying documents based on city, area, and price range sounds possible. The issue arises if you need to use inequalities on different fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter firestore compound query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316462/flutter-firestore-compound-query)

Comment: Ok, I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query in Firestore can contain range conditions on only one field, so you won't be able to filter on both area and price.

See the Firebase documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations), which says:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Comment: Is there the same dependency in the realtime database?

Comment: Yes. Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property altogether. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924. But in that case too, you can only order/range filter on one value. Reading my answer there might explain better why that limit exists though, so I'd still recommend that.